# Как реализовать меню?

Tags: python, вконтакте, api

Пользуюсь Long poll для получения последних обновлений с группы, он мне возвращает сообщения пользователей каждые 25 секунд, после чего я могу работать с ними и т.д.

Нужно реализовать меню с подменю для пользователя в виде нумерованного списка.

Проблема в следующем - например отправил пользователь слово "Меню", бот отправил ему такое меню:

```
Меню, для выбора отправь цифру

1. Магазин
2. Информация
3. Друзья
```

Представим, что человек отправит 1, я обработаю это и верну ему меню магазина:

```
Магазин
Для покупки отправь цифру!
1. Мясо 1$
2. Банан 3$
3. Апельсин 4$
Для выхода напишите "Назад"
```

И тут появляется проблема - в моем случае если человек введет 1, она обработается дважды, т.к. точно такой ввод обрабатывается и в первом меню.

Нужно реализовать некую "область видимости", чтобы бот понимал в каком из меню или подменю находится пользователь.

Мой код сейчас(Принимает сообщения и отправляет такое же только голосовое и картинку):

```
import vk
from config import *
from requests import *
import os
import json
session = vk.Session(access_token = VK_API_ACCESS_TOKEN)
api = vk.API(session, v = VK_API_VERSION)
# Первый запрос к LongPoll: получаем server и key
longPoll = api.groups.getLongPollServer(group_id = GROUP_ID)
server, key, ts = longPoll['server'], longPoll['key'], longPoll['ts']
while True:
    # Последующие запросы: меняется только ts
    longPoll = post('%s'%server, data = {'act': 'a_check',
                                         'key': key,
                                         'ts': ts,
                                         'wait': 25}).json()

    if longPoll['updates'] and len(longPoll['updates']) != 0: #Если longPoll вернул обновления, количество которых не равно нулю продолжаем
        for update in longPoll['updates']: #Выполняем for пока не кончатся количество упдейтов в longPoll
            if update['type'] == 'message_new': #Если обновления - сообщение
                # Помечаем сообщение от этого пользователя как прочитанное
                api.messages.markAsRead(peer_id = update['object']['user_id'])
                textMessage = update['object']['body']
                # Запрашиваем имя пользователя
                name = api.users.get(user_ids = update['object']['user_id'])[0]['first_name']
                # Скачиваем аудиофайл "Привет, %name%" с Яндекс.SpeechKit и загружаем на сервера ВК
                with open('audio.mp3', 'wb') as out_stream:
                    req = get('https://tts.voicetech.yandex.net/generate?text=Привет твой текст: %s!&format=opus&lang=ru-RU&speaker=jane&emotion=good&key=%s'%(textMessage, YANDEX_API_KEY), stream = True)
                    for chunk in req.iter_content(1024):
                        out_stream.write(chunk)

                afile = post(api.docs.getMessagesUploadServer(type = 'audio_message', peer_id = update['object']['user_id'])['upload_url'], files = {'file': open('audio.mp3', 'rb')}).json()['file']
                doc = api.docs.save(file = afile, title = 'Voice message')[0]

                # Загружаем картинку на сервера ВК
                pfile = post(api.photos.getMessagesUploadServer(peer_id = update['object']['user_id'])['upload_url'], files = {'photo': open('python.jpeg', 'rb')}).json()
                photo = api.photos.saveMessagesPhoto(server = pfile['server'], photo = pfile['photo'], hash = pfile['hash'])[0]

                # Отправляем сообщение "Привет, %name%" с аудиосообщением из Яндекс.SpeechKit и картинкой
                api.messages.send(peer_id = update['object']['user_id'], message = 'Привет, твой текст: %s &#128521;'%textMessage, attachment = 'doc%s_%s,photo%s_%s'%(doc['owner_id'], doc['id'], doc['owner_id'], photo['id']))

                # Удаляем файл Яндекс.SpeechKit
                os.remove(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'audio.mp3'))


    # Меняем ts для следующего запроса
    ts = longPoll['ts']
```

Comment: А вы не могли бы приложить хоть какой-то код, который у вас есть и показать на нем, что не работает? [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Пока что это выглядит как заказ на фрилансе.

Comment: Добавил. Просто тут скорее проблема не в коде, а проблема проектирования

Comment: Создайте какую-нибудь переменную, которая будет принимать значения, в зависимости от того подменю, в котором находится пользователь и соответственно после получения ответа проверяйте значение переменной и узнавайте в каком подменю находится сейчас пользователь